# Create package for update on monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk

I would like to create a package in release mode, just for distribution a update package. What I would like to know if it is possible to remove that systems dlls from the apk, and update only my assemblies at the installed app.

Thanks,

Allan Vasconcellos